# docstring (triple quotes) in iPython/Jupyter with autoclose brackets/quotes?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, docstring

I'm trying to use `docstrings` w/ triple-quotes in my **Jupyter notebooks** using Python 2.7 .

I can disable the autoclose brackets/quotes thing but I'm quite keen on them; major increase in workflow.

**Does anyone know how to do triple quotes without over-quoting while keeping the autoclose feature?**

If I press the `"` key `3x` I get `""""""`;
If I press it `3x` and `delete` once, I get `""""` pressing; and
If I press it `3x` and `delete` twice, I get `""`

Annoying, right? **How can I have the best of both worlds (autoclose | docstrings) ?**

This is a pretty low-level question, but I haven't seen an easy fix anywhere so the answer should be useful for the community. If you downvote, can you explain why this is a poor question please?

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong. When you type three " your cursor is at the middle of the resulting six. Thus, anything you type is within the string and has been auto-closed.

Comment: @MarcJ I tried the double triple quotes but it's not compiling

Comment: Type this exact string of characters: `"""This is working` without clicking or otherwise moving the cursor. The result will be a correcly formatted string, because it will have auto-closed the string.Therefore you have both strings and autoclose.

Comment: perfect. I was trying to type 3 at a time in a different way. If you put this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: While it may be correct in theory, it is often annoying in practice, when, for example, you want to switch a single quote to a triple quote because your string is getting too long.

Comment: (Yeah you can highlight the string and pressing the quote button will put a quote on both sides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. When you type three " your cursor is at the middle of the resulting six. Thus, anything you type is within the string and has been auto-closed.

Type this exact string of characters: `"""This is working` without clicking or otherwise moving the cursor. The result will be a correcly formatted string, because it will have auto-closed the string. Therefore you have both strings and autoclose.