# Python, unexpected EOF while parsing error

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in Python, having used R quite a lot before.

I am trying to write a multiline string which is very straightforward in R but I receive an error that stumps me, I have googled around everywhere but the suggested solutions have not worked.

When I try to use parentheses as I have seen suggested:

```
multiline = ("Hello,"
            " my name is"
            " James")
```

I receive:

```
multiline = ("Hello,"
  File "<ipython-input-56-f67f7efad636>", line 1
    multiline = ("Hello,"
                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Similarly I tried triple quotes, also suggested:

```
multiline = """Hello,
            my name is
            James"""
```

I receive:

```
multiline = """Hello,
  File "<ipython-input-58-0879a928a2ee>", line 1
    multiline = """Hello,
                         ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

I am sure I will be missing something blindingly obvious to more experienced Python users but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: What are you using to interpret this Python code?

Comment: @ScottHunter The error indicates that this is happening in IPython.

Comment: Is IPython good?

Comment: Can't reproduce the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Ucb.png) or [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV6Jz.png) error

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce these error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docstring (triple quotes) in iPython/Jupyter with autoclose brackets/quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506265/docstring-triple-quotes-in-ipython-jupyter-with-autoclose-brackets-quotes)

Comment: @NBrittain, I can't reproduce either one. I copy-paste them directly to python or ipython REPL, and it works fine. Maybe you have something else in your code that's interfering? Is it is only those 3 lines?

Comment: I think you have a unclosed quotes somewhere check it.

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer unfortunately the link you sent didn't answer it, thanks though. I am using Spyder and the errors I get are appearing in the IPython console if that helps.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your entire screen as soon as you get this error? I've used Spyder and still can't reproduce what you're showing. Maybe there's something else that might hint on what's happening.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got it. Did you use "Run Selection or Current Lien (F9)" in Spyder? I got the same error

Comment: If so, you're supposed to select all the text to use that command, or use the `Run current cell` (Ctrl+Enter, Shift+Enter) so it evaluates all the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is neither an issue with python, ipython or spyder. The mistake is using the incorrect command to run your code. You probably used `Run Selection or Current Line`, while the cursor was in the first line of the multiline strings. This command doesn't consider the context, so it essentially pastes the line into the interpreter and runs. Your first error was caused by python not finding the closing parentheses. Your second error is python not finding the closing triple quotes. In spyder, one typically makes code cells with `#%%` and runs them with `CTRL+ENTER` or `SHIFT+ENTER`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Working now I knew deep down I would be missing something obvious, I was mixing up the commands for running the code lines as it's a bit different in R which doesn't have the concept of 'cells'.

Comment: Thanks K.Cl and all for other suggestions and help.

Comment: Hey there, consider upvoting and marking the best answers to your questions in the future, it helps people know if a post was correctly solved at a glance.